# BitBucket: Allow reviews post merge (a la GitHub)

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, github-codereviews

In Bitbucket, on any Pull Request, reviews are disabled after the PR is merged.

I'd like to continue to allow reviews after a PR is merged.  Is this possible?

NOTE: I am **not** asking about requiring review approval pre-merge, though I may or may not have those requirements as well.  I want post-merge reviews.

In Github, by way of comparison, it is possible to "review" a PR even after it is merged.

[image: Github's Post Merge Review Feature]

I tried clicking the greyed-out "review" button after merging, which obviously did nothing.  If the page is reloaded the "review" button is entirely gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update!

The post-merge approval feature has been reinstated.

See: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22396

Original:

I have been in contact with a wonderful Product Manager at Atlassian, and he let me know that this used to be an accidental "feature" of BitBucket, which they considered a bug, and fixed as of several months ago.  This is why people have a memory of post-merge reviews, which seem to no longer be possible (because, they indeed are no longer possible).

He explained that once they "fixed" the bug they heard from users who had built workflows around it, and wanted the "bug/feature" back.

There is a public issue tracker for this if you are interested in weighing in on it!

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-22396

Atlassian has not yet decided if/when/how they will bring the "bug/feature" back.